# How to fix this error from my code program

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How can I fix this program I use Java Spring MVC?  I want to input data containing dates in the database, but it shows errors.  How can I fix it?

This is my code in **entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="tb_transaksi_penjualan")
public class TransaksiPenjualan {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String customer;
@DateTimeFormat(pattern ="MM/dd/yyyy")
private Date tanggal;
private String barang;
private int jumlah;
private int harga;
private int total;
private Long customer_id;
private Long barang_id;
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}
public void setCustomer(String customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}
public Date getTanggal() {
    return tanggal;
}
public void setTanggal(Date tanggal) {
    this.tanggal = tanggal;
}
public String getBarang() {
    return barang;
}
public void setBarang(String barang) {
    this.barang = barang;
}
public int getJumlah() {
    return jumlah;
}
public void setJumlah(int jumlah) {
    this.jumlah = jumlah;
}
public int getHarga() {
    return harga;
}
public void setHarga(int harga) {
    this.harga = harga;
}
public int getTotal() {
    return total;
}
public void setTotal(int total) {
    this.total = total;
}
public Long getCustomer_id() {
    return customer_id;
}
public void setCustomer_id(Long customer_id) {
    this.customer_id = customer_id;
}
public Long getBarang_id() {
    return barang_id;
}
public void setBarang_id(Long barang_id) {
    this.barang_id = barang_id;
}



}
```

This is my code from **controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/transaksipembelian/save")
public class TransaksiPembelianSaveController {


@Autowired
private TransaksiPembelianRepository transaksiPembelianRepository;

@ModelAttribute("transaksipembelian")
private TransaksiPembelian getTransaksiPembelian(@RequestParam(value="id", required = false) Long id)
{
    if(id==null)
        return new TransaksiPembelian();
    else
        return transaksiPembelianRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String form() {
    return "tambahtransaksipembelian";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submit(@ModelAttribute("transaksipembelian") TransaksiPembelian transaksipembelian ) {

    System.out.println(transaksipembelian.toString());
    transaksiPembelianRepository.save(transaksipembelian);

    return "redirect:/transaksipembelian";
}

}
```

This is message from **error**:

> Field error in object 'transaksipenjualan' on field 'tanggal':
>   rejected value [2019-07-15]; codes
>   [typeMismatch.transaksipenjualan.tanggal,typeMismatch.tanggal,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [transaksipenjualan.tanggal,tanggal]; arguments []; default
>   message [tanggal]]; default message [Failed to convert property value
>   of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for
>   property 'tanggal'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date]
>   for value '2019-07-15'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value
>   [2019-07-15]]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have provided the date pattern for `tanggal` field as `MM/dd/yyyy` but you are supplying `2019-07-15`. Either change the pattern to `yyyy-MM-dd` or the supplied value to `07/15/2019`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you are seeing appears to be saying that you attempted to save/create a `TransaksiPenjualan` entity using a literal date string for `tanggal` of `2019-07-15`.  Based on the `@DateTimeFormat` annotation, you should be using the format `MM/dd/yyyy`.

You may resolve this by passing in the literal `07/15/2019`.

Answer (score -1):

You should change the value format of the *2019-07-15* to *07/15/2019*. Because, You are using `@DateTimeFormat(pattern ="MM/dd/yyyy")` this annotation to format the *tanggal*.

Comment: Same as other answers, only half an hour late.